# BAT if exist %environment variable folder% (System folders)

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, environment

i'd like to test if %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Folder exists but it seems like if EXIST doesn't like environment variables :/

my way would be :

```
if EXIST %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Folder (
    set VAR=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Folder
)
```

no matter how i try, it always outputs false...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Folder" (
    set "VAR=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Folder"
)
```

Comment: To add an explanation:  You need the quotes around the whole thing because %programfiles(x86)% almost always resolves to a path with spaces in it.

Comment: never thought about that, works wonderful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To check whether an environment variable exists:

```
if defined VARIABLE echo Yep, it's defined.
```

The following also works and prints the current value of the variable if set.

```
set VARIABLE && echo Found it! || echo Nope, sorry!
```

Note that SET also responds to prefixes, though, so if you have a var named VARIABLE, then "set var" and "set v" will also return true.

Not the question you asked, but it was how I read the title, so somebody else might have the same question.

Comment: thanks for the information though :) i'll make the title more concrete

Comment: `if defined VARIABLE ...` is simpler and more precise.

Comment: Good call on 'if defined'.  Updated the answer.